# How do I read the data from text file into a variable so I can change the color based on the value?

Tags: javascript, html, text-files

The goal of my project is to read a stream of constantly changing data from a text file into a html file and then changing the font color.

I have tried multiple ways of reading in a text file such as using an iframe and attempting to use the fetch command but was unable to successfully use these to complete my goal.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function print() {
  fetch("test.txt")
    .then(function(response) { return response.text; })
    .then(function(text) {
      var num = parseInt(text);
    if(num>250){
    num=fontcolor("green")
  }
    else()
    {
    num=fontcolor("red")
  }
    });
 }
setInterval(print, 1000); //run function print() every 1 second
  </script>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1">
</body>
```

The outcome should be an html file that when opened in a browser will display the number in the text file and change the color based on the number given.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not fetch text file in local machine for security reason.

You can refer this link for update security for 
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

You can host your file to free host. I corrected your `.then(response => response.text())`

Corrected

```
 <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function print() {
      fetch("test.txt")
        .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        var num = parseInt(text);
        if(num>250){
         console.log(num);
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
        else
        {
        //num=fontcolor("red")
        console.log(num);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      }

      })

     }
    setInterval(print, 1000); //run function print() every 1 second
      </script>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1">
    </body>
```

http://viethien.000webhostapp.com/fetchfile.html